# Liferay + Struts2 There is no Action mapped for namespace /testPortlet1 and action name startTestPortlet1, why?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, content-management-system, liferay

I am absolutly new in Liferay portlet development and I have the following problem.

When I try to add my first portlet (developed by me) in the portlet I obtein this error message:

> testPortlet1 is temporarily unavailable.

And in the stacktrace of my IDE I see this error message:

```
2014-12-19 11:37:55,874 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] ERROR commons.CommonsLogger.error(38) - Could not find action
There is no Action mapped for namespace /testPortlet1 and action name startTestPortlet1. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:189)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:61)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
..............................................................................
..............................................................................
..............................................................................
11:37:55,883 ERROR [PortletServlet:96] javax.portlet.PortletException: Could not find action startTestPortlet1
javax.portlet.PortletException: Could not find action startTestPortlet1
    at org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr168Dispatcher.serviceAction(Jsr168Dispatcher.java:454)
    at org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr168Dispatcher.render(Jsr168Dispatcher.java:322)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:101)
..............................................................................
..............................................................................
..............................................................................
Caused by: There is no Action mapped for namespace /testPortlet1 and action name startTestPortlet1. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:189)
..............................................................................
..............................................................................
..............................................................................
11:37:55,892 ERROR [jsp:154] There is no Action mapped for namespace /testPortlet1 and action name startTestPortlet1. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:189)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:61)
..............................................................................
..............................................................................
..............................................................................
```

So this is the **structs.xml** section related to my portlet:

```
<package name="TestPortlet1Package" extends="struts-portlet-default" namespace="/">
    <action name="startTestPortlet1" class="TestPortlet1Action" method="startTestPortlet1">
        <result name="success">/testPortlet1/testPortlet1.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

This is my JSP view (definied inside the **\Web\src\main\webapp\testPortlet1\testPortlet1.jsp**):

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %>
<style>
    .portlet-topper#portlet_SliderNewsPortlet_WAR_KMPortlets, .portlet-title#portlet_SliderNewsPortlet_WAR_KMPortlets {
        display: none
    }

    .portlet#portlet_SliderNewsPortlet_WAR_KMPortlets, .portlet-content#portlet_SliderNewsPortlet_WAR_KMPortlets {
        border: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: 0;

    }
</style>
<hr style="height:1px;border:none;color:#1d8843;background-color:#1d8843;width: 98%" size="4px">
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="homePortletTitle">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;"><img src="/km-theme/images/km-icons/section_icon_focus.png"></td>
                    <th style="">TestPortlet1</th>
                    <td style="">Hello World Portlet</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Hello World !!!</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this is my portlet configuration definied into **portlet.xml** file:

```
<portlet>

    <portlet-name>testPortlet1</portlet-name>
    <display-name>testPortlet1</display-name>
    <portlet-class>org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr168Dispatcher</portlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <name>viewNamespace</name>
        <value>/testPortlet1</value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <name>defaultViewAction</name>
        <value>startTestPortlet1</value>
    </init-param>

    <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>

    <supports>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        <portlet-mode>VIEW</portlet-mode>
    </supports>

    <portlet-info>
        <title>testPortlet1</title>
    </portlet-info>

</portlet>
```

What am I missing? How can I solve this issue? I am going crazy.

Tnx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why my first "Hello World" LifeRay portlet result to be "temporarily unavailable."?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27562829/why-my-first-hello-world-liferay-portlet-result-to-be-temporarily-unavailable)

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between the package namespace defined in the struts.xml and the `viewNamespace` in the porlet.xml. Solution: fix the struts.xml

```
<package name="TestPortlet1Package" 
         extends="struts-portlet-default" 
         namespace="/testPortlet1">
```